# syntax error: unexpected end of file (expecting "fi")

Tags: linux, bash

So I have a simple script running in an IF statement. I always get:
syntax error: unexpected end of file (expecting "fi")
I am wondering what could be the possible solution for this ?

```
def call(Map config) {
    withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', credentialsId: 'JENKINS_AWS'],
      sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'JENKINS-SSH', keyFileVariable: 'SSH_KEY')]) {
        sh """
            #!/bin/bash
            source add_ssh_key "${SSH_KEY}"           
            source init_env "${TARGET_STAGE}"
            source create-bastion-pod "${PROMETHEUS_PUSHGATEWAY}" "${PROMETHEUS_PUSHGATEWAY_PORT}"  
            if [ ${TARGET_STAGE} == 'dev' ]; then
               cat <<-EOF | curl --data-binary @- \${BASTION_URL}/metrics/job/sone_job 
            # TYPE some_metric counter
            some_metric{label="val1"} 42 
            EOF
            fi
            delete-bastion-pod
        """
    }
}
```

Comment: The closing delimiter does not appear to be indented with a tab. Basically, the parser sees the end of the script while still parsing the here document.

Comment: What's with the triple quotes?  Is this in python?

Comment: @WilliamPursell A now-deleted comment mentioned Groovy.

Comment: @JeffHolt Yes indeed :)

Comment: `curl` should inherit its stdin from `sh`, so you can probably do `cat ... | sh ...`, but it's not clear how this is being executed.  Also, there seems to be a stray backtick which will probably cause havoc.

Comment: The `<<-` heredoc is not getting terminated properly.  Rather than trying to manipulate the whitespace so that Groovy passes the right thing to sh, just stop using a heredoc and use `printf '%s\n%s\n' '# TYPE some_metric counter' 'some_metric{label="val1"} 42'`

Comment: i honestly see no reason why i should discard heredoc logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<<-` only strips *tabs* from the here-document; your closing delimiter appears to be indented (according to what Groovy actually presents to the shell) with a couple of spaces. Try something like

```
    sh """
        #!/bin/bash
        if [ ${TARGET_STAGE} == 'dev' ]; then
           cat <<EOF | curl --data-binary @- \${BASTION_URL}/metrics/job/some_job 
        # TYPE some_metric counter
        some_metric{label="val1"} 42 
        EOF
        fi
    """
```

Note that as far as the shell executing the script is concerned, the here-document and the closing `EOF` aren't indented at all.

Comment: I would change `-EOF` to `<<-` for more clarity.  The `EOF` is not really relevant to the type of heredoc.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Same issue!! :/

Comment: What are you using to indent the script itself? If you aren't using the same kind of whitespace on every line, what you see may not be what Groovy is actually passing to the shell. (I'm thinking about mixed spaces and tabs at the beginning of each line.)

Comment: I edited the original post with the whole groovy script. please take a look at it – 
@chepner

Comment: Please verify that your editor isn't inserting *any* tabs in the indented lines.